# Unable to Exit Python Script (Need To Press Enter to Exit)

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a python script which executes the following command using subprocess, but it gets stuck when some error occurs:

```
import subprocess
COMMAND = " Application.exe arg1 arg2"
process = subprocess.Popen(COMMAND, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)

while process.poll() is None:
output = process.stdout.readline()
print output,
```

output:

> There was a communication problem.
> Failed.
>
> Press enter to exit...

Because of the above output, my program is not able to exit until I press any key manually.  Please help show me how to handle the above response and exit my code. The above program works good if there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the last two lines of your code (within the `while` loop) need to be properly indented:

```
import subprocess
COMMAND = " Application.exe arg1 arg2"
process = subprocess.Popen(COMMAND, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)

while process.poll() is None:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    print output,
```

Second, if your `COMMAND` finishes too quickly, then your `while` loop may end before you've read the data completely.  To remedy this issue, use the `communicate()` method:

```
output = process.communicate()[0]
print output,
```

Here are the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) related to `Popen.communicate()`

Comment: My pleasure!  Happy to help.

Comment: @user1891916: [you don't need `.poll()` here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Comment: @user1891916: I don't see how the answer could have possibly solved the *"Press enter to exit..."* issue. You need `stdin=DEVNULL` or `stdin=PIPE` and either  `process.stdin.close()` or implicitly via `process.communicate()` (`.communicate()` without `stdin=PIPE` won't produce EOF on the application's stdin)